# Issues with WIDTH and HEIGHT percentages in a DIV via CSS (firefox doesn't work)

Tags: firefox, css, height, width, centering

My brain is overflow about this issue, so let me share my frustration in order to look for someone having the same experience and, luckily, finding a solution.

The thing is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4d2E/

In chrome, percentages work fine, but when trying the same in Firefox (latest version) the content div is not expanding horizontally and vertically anymore.

I've analyzed every similar question over here, but I can't find any valid answer.

Thanks in advance

P.S.: I've tried to use block display instead of the 'box' one in the 'content' layer, but still having the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're using XUL box layout.  I suggest not doing that.  `-moz-box` is NOT CSS flexbox layout, as you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `display: -moz-box` for body. If you remove it everything works fine. It appears to be a bug, so I suggest filing a report in the [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org).

Comment: if you remove -moz-box then Firebox use traditional block display and the FlexBox layout is off.

What I need is to be able to use FlexBox because I'm trying to do some vertical centering. By the way, Chrome works like a charm with this stuff :)

Thanks for giving a try

Comment: That's why I'm saying that it's a bug. Which sums up nicely the answer to the question «Why it doesn't work?» Features with vendor prefixes tend to have them — they **are** experimental after all.